# Postgres update query: only last letter from entire string get inserted

Tags: python, postgresql

I am working on python web app using docker. At startup I need to create and initialize the tables with some default value, for that I have created `queries.sql` script.

```
# queries.sql

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS person (
    id          serial primary key,
    address  varchar(2000)
);


INSERT INTO person (address)
   VALUES ('some_default_value');
```

The table gets created and row gets inserted `successfully`.

Now, from `web UI`, I have field address using `textarea` where user can enter the address.
and I am updating that in above table.

I am using `psycog2`.

```
def update(query: str, vars_list: list[Any]):
   # psycog 2 connection engine code
   
   cursor.executemany(query=query, vars_list=vars_list)
   
   conn.commit()


def save(data: str):

   query: str = """
      UPDATE person
         SET address = %s
         WHERE id = 1;
         """

   vars_list: list[Any] = list(tuple(data,))
   
   update(query=query, vars_list=vars_list)
```

While debugging, data from textarea comes fully. say eg user types `address` as

```
aaa
bbb
```

When user click save button, `update query` gets executed only `last letter` from entire address gets `inserted/updated` as
`b`

what I am missing?

Comment: `data = 'bbb' list(tuple(data,))   ['b', 'b', 'b']`. See the problem? Actually it is the first letter.

Comment: Hi Adrian, Thanks for pointing it. I am new to sql, I was trying to create a row tuple but it went other way. I guess tuple is not mandatory it can be any iterable, As `select` returns `list[tuples]`, so I was trying to pass data as `list[tuple]` for `update` query.